# How does "go get" get to know what version control system to use with remote repos?

Tags: go

I am new to golang. I learned that `go get` serves as a package manager and contact remote repos with various version control systems.

So, given a package import path, how does `go get` decide which VCS to use?  I always see below query string in the reqeust:

```
?go-get=1
```

So seems some protocol/convention here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the nice things about Go is that everything is in, well, Go :-) Including almost all of the standard library and tools.

In [`cmd/go/vcs.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/vcs.go) we can see how this is done, and in [`cmd/go/alldocs.go`](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/alldocs.go) it is documented.

Specifically, look at `repoRootForImportPath`:

```
// repoRootForImportPath analyzes importPath to determine the
// version control system, and code repository to use.
func repoRootForImportPath(importPath string, security securityMode) (*repoRoot, error) {
```

What this does is:

1. `vcsPaths` holds a static lists of "known hosts". For some (e.g. GitHub) this is easy and we can just set the VCS. For others (e.g. BitBucket) a callback function is used which examines the URL to see which repo can be used.
2. If that fails, it tries to look at a "VCS extension" in the path, such as `example.com/foo.git` or `example.com/foo.git/dir`.
3. And finally `go get` will look for a `go-import` meta tag, which looks like:

   ```
   <meta name="go-import" content="example.com/path git https://github.com/Example/repo.git">
   ```

   Also see `parseMetaGoImports()`. [Vanity Imports with Hugo](https://npf.io/2016/10/vanity-imports-with-hugo/) is a nice introduction on how to use this.

There is no real "auto-detection" mechanism. So if you repo lives at `https://example.com/stuff` then `go get example.com/stuff` will *not* work. You *need* the extension or meta tags.

The `go-get=1` parameter is added so that it's easy for website builders to see that this is a request from `go get`, which may be useful in some cases.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the implementation location. And as a real-world example, the HTML page at `https://golang.org/x/net/html` contains the `go-import` meta tag.